# метод json.loads(str) не работает

Tags: python, json, файлы, python-3.8

Содержимое файла "Зарегистрированные_пользователи.txt":

```
{'User_Name': 'Ivan', 'User_Surname': 'Макаронов', 'User_Nickname': 'Ванёк228', 'User_Password': 'пароль4183ш', 'User_Number': 8889996526, 'User_ID': 839166644277, 'User_DateRegistration': '2002-01-01'}
```

Содержимое файла "Меню админа.py":

```
import json

with open("C:/Users/Администратор/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/My_projects/Project2/База данных-данные пользователей/Зарегистрированные_пользователи.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace("'",'"')
        print(line)
        line_dict = json.loads(line)
        print(line_dict)
```

При вызове файла "Меню админа.py" выводит:

```
{"User_Name": "Ivan", "User_Surname": "Макаронов", "User_Nickname": "Ванёк228", "User_Password": "пароль4
183ш", "User_Number": 8889996526, "User_ID": 839166644277, "User_DateRegistration": "2002-01-01"}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Администратор/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Все мои проекты)/Серьёзные проекты/База данных-данные пользователей/Меню админа.py", line 8, in <module>
    line_dict = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 337,
in loads
    raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Как исправить эту ошибку??
Оба файла (txt и py) кодированы в utf-8.
Формат файла txt тут думаю не виноват,так как в данном коде я считываю файл через цикл for посторочно с помощью метода readlines, а тип переменной line - это string.

Comment: Например, сделайте то, что предлагает текст ошибки — замените `encoding="utf-8"` на `encoding="utf-8-sig"`

Comment: Помогло.Спасибо огромное andreymal!

Answer (score 0):

Уберите русские символы из путей.

Comment: Возникшая здесь ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к русским символам в путях